# how to use multiple websockets on the same page?

Tags: python, django, websocket

I have recently tried to create a comment and delete it via the websockets and have succeeded in doing this but when I use the two together only one of them works like deleting the comment only.
I have used multiple websockets for doing this :

```
    var socket_create = 'ws://' + window.location.host + '/create_comment'
    var socket_delete = 'ws://' + window.location.host + '/delete_comment'
    var socket1 = new ReconnectingWebSocket(socket_create)
    var socket2 = new ReconnectingWebSocket(socket_delete)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think using two WebSockets for this is overkilling. You could use only one and implement the `create_comment` and `delete_comment` at the message level.

For instance:

```
var crud_socket = new ReconnectingWebSocket(socket_url);

crud_socket.onmessage = function(event) {
    // Assuming here you're using json.
    var data = JSON.parse(even.data)
    action = data.action;

    if (action === 'delete') {
        // delete here ...
    }
    if action === 'create' {
       // create here ...
    }
}
```

**Remember you're using Django ...**

... so you can follow this pattern:

Use WebSockets to notifying the client (browser) of some event that just happened in the server, an object was created, an object was deleted, some task has finished, etc...

If you want to perform a CRUD action you just make an AJAX request to a Django view. So, following this pattern, creating a message should look like this:

1. Your javascript loads and you web socket get connected.
2. You press some button that triggers an AJAX call to a Django view.
3. Such Django view receives the data and creates and saves an instance of `Message` (or whatever model you implemented for represent a message).
4. When the message is created, a signal receiver (see [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signals/)) send a message to the web socket.
5. Your js code receives that message an act accordingly.

Recommended: [Django Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)